# How do I create terminal commands in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, shell, terminal, command

I'm writing a c++ program and I want people to be able to operate it from the terminal. The only thing I know how to do is `cin` which, though upon receiving the program could act, I wouldn't call a command.
Thanks!!

Comment: Hä?? Don't get your question, what did you try?

Comment: That's pretty much the basis.  Add the ability to invoke other programs and builtin functions, variable expansion, quoting, and globbing, and you have a shell.  Instead parse and interpret some programming language, and you have a REPL (read-execute-print-loop) console.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Command: " << argv[0] << "\n";
    for(int loop = 1;loop < argc; ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << "Arg: " << loop << ": " << argv[loop] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program, use the alternate `int main` signature, which accepts command line arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
// argc = number of command line arguments passed in
// argv = array of strings containing the command line arguments
// Note: the executable name is argv[0], and is also "counted" towards the argc count
```

I also suggest put the location of your executable in the operating system's search path, so that you can call it from anywhere without having to type in the full path. For example, if your executable name is `foo`, and located at `/home/me` (on Linux), then use the following command (ksh/bash shell):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me`
```

On Windows, you need to append your path to the environment variable `%PATH%`.

Then call the `foo` program from anywhere, with the usual:

```
foo bar qux
(`bar` and `qux` are the command line arguments for foo)
```